# How to format multiple entries in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using the following code to get a list of direct reports in Powershell:

```
import-module activedirectory

$identity = read-host "Enter username:"

Get-ADUser $identity -Properties directReports | select-object {$_.directReports} | export-csv "DirectReports-$identity.csv"
```

This outputs all of the direct reports to one row, such as "CN=User1,CN=User2,CN=User3".....

How can I modify this so it outputs each user to its own row?

Comment: I've neither used nor seen the `directReports` property, but it sounds like you want to [`-split` on the ","](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't the cleanest solution:

```
Get-ADUser $identity -Properties directReports | select-object -expandproperty directReports|foreach-object{$_.split(",")[0].replace("CN=","")}| export-csv "DirectReports-$identity.csv"
```

You'll get each person's name (only) on its own line in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser $identity -Properties directReports | 
Select-Object Name,@{n='DirectReports';e={$_.directReports.Split(',CN=',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join ';'}} | 
Export-Csv "DirectReports-$identity.csv"
```

Comment: This seems to remove the commas, but they still output to the same row.

Comment: You don't get just the name from directReports ?

Comment: No, it places all of the names on the same row, only this time without the commas in between them.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice it contains multiple CN items, thought it was a DN. Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry, this produces a blank csv file

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file, first 3 lines would help